# events to be triggered by Reosurce change listener for move

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using Resource Change Listener to track the changes done to my java project. When i move a class from one package to another, it some times triggers Remove even and some time Add event. Is this correct. I was expecting add event on the 2nd package and remove event on the 1st package. I need to track both add and remove, please let me know how this can be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect you to get two `IResourceDelta` with `ADDED` and `REMOVED` kinds. Depending on exactly how the class move is done these might be in two separate `IResourceChangeEvent` events or they may be in one. The resource delta flags may also have `MOVED_FROM` and `MOVED_TO` set.